# Is "lessening the amount" an appropriate expression?

Tags: expressions

I came across the expression "lessening the amount of" several times, even in some formal contexts. But I think the word "lessen" itself has a notion of amount as it means "​to become or make something become smaller". Isn't it  redundant to say "lessening the amount of"?
Please suggest.

Comment: It's not necessarily redundant; in many contexts there could be the potential to lessen other aspects of the same thing. For instance the writer could have the option of "lessening the impact" of something or "lessening the cost" of it.

Comment: I think 'lessening the impact' looks fine I meant the use of 'lessen' with the word 'amount'. I saw some instances such as 'lessening the amount of impact' and 'lessening the amount of information'. For example 'lessening the amount of information' could be written as lessening the information or reducing the amount of information.

Comment: There's a difference between "lessening the amount of information" and "lessening the information". In the first, fewer points of information are given; in the second, less information is given for each point. The difference is subtle and may end up with the same result, but the different words do impart a different emphasis on what is being described.